# Python doesn't save data to sqlite db

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite

This is my code:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect(nnpcconfig.commondb)
cur = conn.cursor()
query = ['2124124', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4', 'test5']
cur.execute("insert into users(id, encpass, sname, name, fname) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", query)
conn.commit
cur.execute("select * from users")
for row in cur:
    print row
```

This code works, returning row fed to it. But it comes out that once script terminated, table is clear again! Where's the mistake? Of course, table users exists.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**You have another mistake:** `conn.commit` instead of `conn.commit()`

Comment: This is the actual problem in the above code that would cause the table to be empty. The connection will close when the script exits.